# Python tell() behaving differently regarding position in the current file

Tags: python

In the book - Core Python Programming, there is following example -

```
>>> f = open('/tmp/x', 'w+')
>>> f.tell()
0
>>> f.write('test line 1\n')  # add 12-char string [0-11]
>>> f.tell()
12
>>> f.write('test line 2\n')  # add 12-char string [12-23]
>>> f.tell()                  # tell us current file location (end))
24
```

When I run the same code in my interpreter, I get 13L in place of 12 and 26L in place of 24. 
I am running python 2.5 on Windows.

Has anything changed regarding behaviour or tell() in versions? How does tell decide the position in the file.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: +1 for mentioning details such as the Python version and OS. So few people do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your file is opened in text mode. In that mode Python on Windows makes a translation between Windows line-endings and Unix line endings. On Windows a line ending is two characters while on Unix it is one (`'\n'`), hence your result is expected.

If you open the file in binary mode, you don't get these translations.

```
f = open('/tmp/x', 'wb+')
```

And you would get 12 and 24 back from `tell()` as well.

Comment: Thanks all for replying. But when I do a f.read() on the file, I get '\n'. I do not see '\r\n'. How can I read the actual line separator ?

Comment: Found the answer, if I open the file in rb+ mode, I can read the \r\n. Thanks again to all for replying.

Answer (score 1):

It's because newlines in Windows are two characters, CR and LF. On Unix they are just one, LF. By default, Python will convert `\n` to be your OS's notion of a newline.

The `L` you are seeing simply tells you that the number is a long integer.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> f = open('c:\\temp\\foo', 'w+')
>>> f.tell()
0L
>>> f.write('test line 1\n')
>>> f.tell()
13L
>>> g = open('c:\\temp\\bar', 'wb+')
>>> g.tell()
0L
>>> g.write('test line 1\n')
>>> g.tell()
12L
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because of newlines. :) 
On Unix is it '\n' and Mac '\r' and most probably the author of core-python was using this.
You are on Windows and it is '\r\n' and so you are getting additional character counted.